# Stopwatch total time issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timer, stopwatch

I have a project where I have to show time of the query to the server.
Multiple Stopwatches are being used:

> 1) For webservice response(TechDoctimer)
>
> 2) For db response (dbTimer)
>
> 3) For total time of function performance (timer) this timer is "the biggest one", all the other timers are nested inside its performance.

So as a result I have to get 2 numbers (from db and techdoc stopwatch), sum of which would be less then `timer`, but I get something like this:

> Server total response time: 1.351 (seconds)
>
> TechDoc total response time: 1.215 (seconds)
>
> Database prices total response time: 0.67 (seconds)

As you can see TechDoc+Database **>** Server total response time.
I cant understand how could this happen, if only Visual Studio doesn`t do threading on its own.

Here is the code of my function:

```
 public static FullModel GetDetailList(string article)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        Stopwatch dbTimer = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch TechDoctimer = new Stopwatch();

        var db = new TecAllianceEntities();
        FullModel model = new FullModel();
        model.details = new List<DetailModel>();
        List<string> listOfNo = new List<string>();
        int articleId;

        TechDoctimer.Start();
        List<int> listOfIdsFound = RequestDetailIdByArticle(article);
        TechDoctimer.Stop();


        foreach (var item in listOfIdsFound)
        {
            DetailModel detail = new DetailModel();
            detail.oeNumberList = new List<OENumberModel>();
            detail.documents = new List<DocumentModel>();
            detail.attributeList = new List<AttributeModel>();

            articleId = item;

            TechDoctimer.Start();
            string resultFromRequestDetailById = TecAllianceResponce.RequestDetailByIds(articleId);
            TechDoctimer.Stop();

            var result = TecAllianceResponce.GetSorted(resultFromRequestDetailById);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                switch (result[i])
                {
                    case "articleId":
                        detail.articleId = Int32.Parse(result[i + 1]);
                        break;

                    case "articleName":
                        detail.articleName = result[i + 1];
                        break;

                    case "articleNo":
                        detail.articleNo = result[i + 1];
                        listOfNo.Add(result[i + 1]);
                        break;

                    case "articleStateName":
                        detail.articleStateName = result[i + 1];
                        break;

                    case "brandName":
                        if (result[i - 2] == "articleStateName")
                            detail.brandName = result[i + 1];
                        break;

                    case "packingUnit":
                        detail.packingUnit = Int32.Parse(result[i + 1]);
                        break;

                    case "quantityPerPackingUnit":
                        detail.quantityPerPackingUnit = Int32.Parse(result[i + 1]);
                        break;

                    case "docId":
                        detail.hasDocuments = result[i + 1] != "0" ? true : false;
                        DocumentModel newDoc = new DocumentModel()
                        {
                            docId = Int32.Parse(result[i + 1]),
                            docFileName = result[i - 1],
                            docTypeName = result[i + 5]
                        };
                        newDoc.docURL = "http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-3-0/documents/367/" + newDoc.docId + "/" + 0;
                        detail.documents.Add(newDoc);
                        break;

                    case "oeNumber":
                        detail.hasDocuments = result[i + 1] != "0" ? true : false;
                        OENumberModel newOE = new OENumberModel()
                        {
                            brandName = result[i - 1],
                            oeNumber = result[i + 1]
                        };
                        detail.oeNumberList.Add(newOE);
                        break;

                    case "attrName":
                        AttributeModel newAttr = new AttributeModel()
                        {
                            attrName = result[i + 1]
                        };
                        for (int j = i; j <= i + 12; j++)
                        {
                            if (result[j] == "attrValue") newAttr.attrValue = result[j + 1];
                            if (result[j] == "attrUnit") newAttr.attrUnit = result[j + 1];
                        }
                        if (newAttr.attrUnit == null) newAttr.attrUnit = "";
                        detail.attributeList.Add(newAttr);
                        break;
                }
            }
            model.details.Add(detail);
        }

        dbTimer.Start();
        if (listOfNo.Any())
        {
            var queryPrices = db.PRECES.Where(p => listOfNo.Contains(p.RAZOTAJA_KODI)).Select(p => new { p.RAZOTAJA_KODI, p.REALIZ_CENA }).ToList();
            dbTimer.Stop();
            foreach (var item in model.details)
            {
                try
                {
                    item.price = queryPrices.Where(q => q.RAZOTAJA_KODI == item.articleNo).Select(q => q.REALIZ_CENA).First();
                }
                catch
                {
                    item.price = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dbTimer.Stop();
        }

        timer.Stop();
        TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
        TimeSpan TechDocUsageTime = TechDoctimer.Elapsed;
        TimeSpan dbRequestTime = dbTimer.Elapsed;

        model.dbTimeTaken = dbRequestTime.Seconds + "." + dbRequestTime.Milliseconds;
        model.TimeTaken = timeTaken.Seconds + "." + timeTaken.Milliseconds;
        model.TimeTechDoc = TechDocUsageTime.Seconds + "." + TechDocUsageTime.Milliseconds;

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use 'model.dbTimeTaken = dbRequestTime.TotalSeconds + "." + dbRequestTime.Milliseconds'.  The Property Second only contains the seconds of the current Minute. So if it takes longer than a minute, you will have a wrong result.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Just use the TotalSeconds property of the TimeSpan instead of combining Seconds and Milliseconds. Also check the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It takes less then 5 sec, usually about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Seeing as you are saving the result to a string, why don't you just use the TimeSpan.ToString() output?

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my problem! Could you write it as an answer, so as i could mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you are saving the result to a string, why don't you just use the TimeSpan.ToString() output?